# Swift ASWebAuthenticationSession callbackURLScheme not calling completion

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, aswebauthenticationsession

I am setting up OAuth for Stripe using Swift/SwiftUI, Firebase, and of course, Stripe. How it works is you make some requests to get the Stripe users account ID, then create another request that spits out the OAuth URL. For testing purposes the url looks like this:

```
https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https://www.brandboost.app/auth-completion&client_id=YOURTESTID
```

Once the auth is complete, Stripe redirects to the given uri. This is very common, but here's where things get weird. As you can see in the auth url above, my uri is a link to a domain I own, but since the URI of a valid domain is http/https. You might be thinking, "just make the URI custom", well you can't.

When adding your custom URI to Stripe, this happens:
[image]

So you have to use a valid URI, meaning the domain you enter doesn't even exist? What am I supposed to do here?

Also, here is my session & the callbackURLScheme:

```
let authSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: "auth-completion") { (url, error) in
   //
}
```

I have used callbacks and URIs before, and I cannot figure out how to get it working. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Should not that `redirect_uri` be 'https://www.brandboost.app/auth-completion..'? Looking at this resource as well: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts but the recommended approach is using the Connect Onboarding, https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts.

Comment: @pgs I have switched to the connect onboarding but am still facing the same problem, you give it a return_url that is redirected to once the auth is completed but it has to be a valid url with http/https - so I can't use a custom uri